# How do I get more debug messages from Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, debugging, jboss, log4j

I haven't been able to get any more console output (to help with debugging) from Hibernate despite setting a few properties in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. For example, adding the line `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` did not, in fact, show SQL statements in the console.

I've also tried playing around with the contents of the `log4j.properties` file - like setting `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug` - with no luck. What am I missing?

---

**Edit:** the contents of the hibernate-service.xml file are

```
<server> 
    <mbean code="org.jboss.hibernate.jmx.Hibernate" 
       name="jboss.har:service=Hibernate_SMS"> 
        <attribute name="DatasourceName">java:/SMS_DS</attribute> 
        <attribute name="Dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</attribute> 
        <attribute name="SessionFactoryName">java:/hibernate/SessionFactory</attribute> 
        <attribute name="CacheProviderClass">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</attribute>
        <attribute name="ShowSqlEnabled">true</attribute>
    </mbean> 
</server>
```

I'm not 100% sure if this actually has any effect, though. That XML file is in the Eclipse project that handles my database stuff, but doesn't seem to be in the JBoss deploy directory.

---

**Edit 2:** This is definitely deployed as a HAR. That said, I'm pretty sure that I need `hibernate.cfg.xml` - I recall having problems when a mapping document was omitted as an entry in that file. I think the HAR is generated using ant - there's a target for it in the build.xml file:

```
<target name="har" depends="prepare" description="Builds the Hibernate HAR file">
    <mkdir dir="${class.root}" />
    <mkdir dir="${distribution.dir}" />

    <jar destfile="${distribution.dir}/${har.name}">                    
        <!-- include the hbm.xml files  -->
        <fileset dir="${class.root}">
            <include name="**/*.hbm.xml"/>
            <include name="com/[redacted]/sms/data/dto/*.class"/>
            <include name="com/[redacted]/sms/data/dto/base/*.class"/>
        </fileset>

        <!-- include jboss-service.xml -->
        <metainf dir="${hibernate.dir}">
            <include name="hibernate-service.xml"/>
        </metainf>
    </jar>
</target>
```

but when I do the ant build with incorrectly-formed xml in the hibernate-service.xml file, it doesn't fail. **Update** Even deleting the file entirely doesn't cause a build to fail. Any ideas here? **End Update**

It sounds like getting Hibernate to output SQL statements should (if everything's set up correctly) take care of it entirely - does that mean that the settings in log4j.properties won't make a difference here? - because that actually *does* change the output when running ant.

**Edit 3:** After running into other weird issues with my data `har`, I deleted the har file entirely and rebuilt it using the `har` ant build target. Suddenly everything's working! Thanks to chessplay for his awesome helpfulness. Can't say I know exactly what did it in the end, but I'd rather acknowledge his efforts than write and accept my own answer; My apologies if you're not a "he."

Comment: `hibernate.show_sql` (or, `ShowSqlEnabled` in JBoss mbean) is independent of logging configuration; if enabled it will always print SQL to console. Setting `org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` in appropriate logger configuration will do the same but to whatever output is configured for logger. Both methods are independent of each other (e.g. if you set both you'll get sql printed twice)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct property name is [hibernate.show_sql](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional) and it definitely works.

Make sure that your `hibernate.cfg.xml` is the right one and it is getting picked up; same goes for your `log4j.properties` file. I know those seem like dumb suggestions, but they account for 98% of "missing logging output" problems.

**Update**: I'll update the answer rather than keep adding comments.
You do need to make sure your `hibernate-service.xml` is picked up by JBoss. The easy way to check is to add a syntax error to it (like omit a closing brace on some element) and see if JBoss blows up during restart :-) It should be packaged into `har` and deployed as part of your build process, so if you realize that it's *not* being picked up by JBoss, that's the place to look. I would get rid of conflicting settings in `hibernate.cfg.xml` (e.g. everything that you're specifying as mbean attributes should not be replicated in `hibernate.cfg.xml`). For that matter, do you even need `hibernate.cfg.xml`? If deployed as `HAR`, your mappings should be automatically scanned / picked up.

Comment: Do I also need to set the log level in log4j.properties? - I did find at first I was working with the wrong copies of those two files, but switched to tooling with the correct copies before I asked here.

Comment: Setting hibernate.show_sql to true should print SQL to console _irregardless_ of logging configuration. Alternatively, you can set `org.hibernate.SQL` log level to DEBUG to direct it to the log file of your choice (as configured in your logging configuration)

Comment: I changed the line to `<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>` but still nothing. :\

Comment: You'll need to provide more info, then. How are you configuring Hibernate's SessionFactory? Within Spring? Or standalone? Can you post your configuration?

Comment: No problem - I figured that would be the case. I'm not actually sure, since I didn't do the initial work of setting everything up. I'm pretty sure that it doesn't use Spring. What would a standalone configuration look like? The Hibernate docs haven't been very helpful here.

Comment: I think it's getting the SessionFactory from JNDI.

Comment: Your code may be getting session factory from JNDI; but the main point of interest here is where SessionFactory is set up. Is the whole thing  running within some app server (judging by JNDI)? If you're not using Spring, you must either have a hibernate.cfg.xml or hibernate.properties somewhere in the classpath plus SessionFactory is being initialized somewhere in code via buildSessionFactory() method.

Comment: The whole thing is running in JBoss. I do have the hibernate.cfg.xml in the classpath as best as I can tell (it's in the root directory of the source folder of the Eclipse project dedicated to database interaction).

Comment: Hibernate is configured as a service via a Hibernate mbean as per http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/ch13.html.

Comment: Ah... that's a different story then. JBoss (not unlike Spring) uses bean properties to specify Hibernate settings. Thus, you need to set `ShowSqlEnabled` attribute on your mbean to true to print sql to console (e.g. `<attribute name="ShowSqlEnabled">true</attribute>`).

Comment: See my edit. I put that attribute into the mbean (though I'm still not sure how JBoss ever sees it) but still no luck.

Comment: Would it be useful to see the console output when starting up JBoss?

Answer (score 8):

I just use the log4j.properties file to log Hibernate statements. For SQL statements, the **log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL** property needs to be set to **debug**, and for SQL parameters/returned values the **log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type** property needs to be set to **trace**.

Here is the log4j.properties file I use:

```
### direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

### Root logger
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout

### Main Hibernate
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug

### log just the SQL
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

### log JDBC bind parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

Comment: For whatever reason, my `log4j.properties` file doesn't seem to affect the console output when JBoss is actually running. However, it does seem to control the output level when I run my ant build script.

Answer (score 1):

Also make shure you're using the correct log4j-configuration.

When running in jboss (you are doing that, right?), you configure log4j-logging in `$JBOSS_HOME/server/<config>/conf/jboss-log4j.xml`.

There are two default appenders; `FILE` writes to `log/server.log` and `CONSOLE` to `stdout` (sometimes redirected `log/console.log`). Adjust threshold on the appender to `DEBUG` in the file or by setting the systemproperty `jboss.server.log.threshold` (depends on which version of jboss you are using).

You'll also need to adjust the logging priority of hibernate by adding a category:

```
<category name="org.hibernate">
  <priority value="DEBUG"/>
</category>
```