# Spring boot hibernate slow startup

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired AppsRepo appRepo;
    @Autowired OrdersRepo ordersRepo;

    @Test
    public void doTest() {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have very simple integration test, hibernate and postgresql database. Only 2 repositories and 1 controller. Running this integration test takes about 62 seconds. What's going on under the hood ?

I have only 2 domain objects and only 2 repositories. Is there any way to speed up test ? Looks like most of the time is taken by hibernate

40 seconds from 62 is spent there -

```
2016-11-18 15:58:52.264  INFO 8424 --- [restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect
2016-11-18 15:59:31.528 DEBUG 8424 --- [restartedMain] o.h.e.j.env.spi.IdentifierHelperBuilder  : JDBC driver metadata reported database stores quoted identifiers in neither upper, lower nor mixed case
```

Comment: Did you try `DevTools`? Here is the link https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3

Comment: enable debugging you will see all for yourself. there's a plenty of actions being performed during the whole spring/hibernate load/bootstrap process. the long loads may be a problem of some connection issues as well - just debug it again.

Comment: @SergeyBenner updated question, nothing really interesting even with debug logging

Comment: @user12384512 what happens after it gets past that point? does it print out any of errors or something else? put debug onto the hibernate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380898/how-do-i-get-more-debug-messages-from-hibernate

Comment: @SergeyBenner All debug and trace logs are already enabled. Can't see anything suspicious. The question contains part of logs where application spend 40 seconds from 60

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this property to your hibernate configuration:

```
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```