# Display Hibernate properties values

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

**Is there any way to display hibernate properties values in console when booting app ?**

Not that relevant but I'm using Spring and Hibernate with JPA persitence.xml files and I'd like to see settings for different properties in order to be sure my configurations files are correctly taken into account (like "hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" or "hibernate.c3p0.timeout")

PS: I know about ***show_sql*** but that's not what I'm looking for :)

Comment: take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380898/how-do-i-get-more-debug-messages-from-hibernate

Comment: Yup I already tried to put
<logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="ALL" />
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" />

But as of now I don't see anything helpful during either startup or query execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My logback.xml contains below lines.

```
<appender name="dailyRollingFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
   ....//some code
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
   ....//some code
</appender>

<logger name="your_package" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>
<root>
    <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender"/>
</root>
```

I have set the level for `org.hibernate` as `DEBUG` due to which following hibernate properties is getting written into log file.

```
java.net.URLClassLoader@35f983a6

excludeUnlistedClasses: false
JTA datasource: null
Non JTA datasource: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@24265b14
Transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL
PU root URL: file:****.jar
Shared Cache Mode: UNSPECIFIED
Validation Mode: AUTO
Jar files URLs []
Managed classes names []
Mapping files names []
Properties [
    hibernate.connection.charSet: UTF-8
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    hibernate.search.default.directory_provider: filesystem
    hibernate.show_sql: false
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: none
    hibernate.format_sql: false
    hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy]
```

Comment: Well ok, so I guess there is an issue with my logback.
I can see logback assigning everything with (-Dlogback.statusListenerClass=ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener) but still after loading JPA/Hibernate .. and no hibernate info at all

Comment: @Florian If you can remote debug then you could see them by debugging

Comment: Ok, when running my junit test with HSQLDB, I got the same output as yours .. I'll try to understand why my tomcat/logback doesn't want to display that but in the meantime this is fine by me! :)